# Prove that a subset is an indicatrix (unitary sphere) in a Minkowski space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces

Suppose that $\pi:(V_1,F_1)\to V_2$ is a linear surjective map, where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces and $F_1$ is a Minkowski norm on $V_1$. Let $\Sigma_1$ be the indicatrix on $V_1$, that is the unitary sphere with respect to $F_1$. Define $\Sigma_2:=\pi(\Sigma_1)$.

If $\Sigma_2$ is an indicatrix with respect to some Mnikowski norm on $V_2$?

Comment: Could you please mention your idea?

Comment: I really have no idea. The point is using this indicatrix I want to define a Minkowski norm on $V_2$. But I even do not know how to prove that a subset is an indicatrix. Maybe someone can prove that it is the board of a convex subset?!?!